# MVC5 ComponentModel.DataAnnotation is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Please tell me why ComponentModel.DataAnnotations is not working here i have done every thing but in vain so tell me where i have mistakes in this code. here i am posting my view along with model.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<form>

    <div id="par" class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BrandCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BrandCode, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BrandCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductSubGroupCode, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 col-ld-2 col-sd-2" })

            <div class="col-md-10">
                @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.ProductSubGroupCode)

              .DataTextField("ProductSubGroupName")
              .DataValueField("ProductSubGroupCode")
              .DataSource(d => d.Read(r => r.Action("GetProductSubGroup", "Product")))
                      .Placeholder("Select Product Sub Group...")
                      .Suggest(true)
                      .HighlightFirst(true)
                )
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductSubGroupCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductGroupCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.ProductGroupCode)
                .MinLength(100)
              .DataTextField("ProductGroupName")
              .DataValueField("ProductGroupCode")
      .DataSource(d => d.Read(r => r.Action("GetProductGroup", "Product")))
                      .Placeholder("Select Product Group...")
                      .Suggest(true)
                      .HighlightFirst(true)
                )
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductGroupCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BrandName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BrandName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BrandName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BrandDescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BrandDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BrandDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Active, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Active)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Active, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SortOrder, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SortOrder, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SortOrder, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" id="Save" class="btn btn-info" />
            <p id="content"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

This is the model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class BrandViewModels
    {

        [Display(Name = "Brand Code")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Brand Code is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"(\S)+", ErrorMessage = "White space is not allowed.")]
        [Remote("IsUniqueBrandCode", "Product", AdditionalFields = "BrandCode", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Brand Code already exists.")]
        public string BrandCode { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public List<ProductSubGroupList> ProductSubGroupList { get; set; }
        public List<ProductGroupList> ProductGroupList { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select product group")]
        [Display(Name = "Product Group")]
        public string ProductGroupCode { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select product sub group")]
        [Display(Name = "Product Sub Group")]
        public string ProductSubGroupCode { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Brand name is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Brand Name")]
        public string BrandName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        public string BrandDescription { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Active")]
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Sort Order")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Sorting order is required")]
        public int? SortOrder { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Validation is not working in view

Comment: Have you enabled client side validation? Have you included the relevant scripts?

Comment: yes i have added all the scripts files in view and client side validation is also enabled

Comment: Why are you using `<form>` (and not `@Html.BeginForm()`)?. Is this form being loaded dynamically? Is `ModelState` invalid in you POST method?

Comment: I think there is no issue with <form> because i several time used <form> and the validation works. ok let me change it, and check.

Comment: yes i check it still not working plz do something

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown. What happens when you post. Is `ModelState` invalid? And Is this form being loaded dynamically?

Comment: it just not validate that require regardless post of form

Comment: I guess you just not going to answer my queries, so best of luck

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have following Appsettings in Web Config

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Please refer [Data Anotation validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157717/mvc4-validation-does-not-work/31158257#31158257)

Comment: yes i have both of these in web.config then why validation is not working i have checked everything

Comment: Did you tried  `@Html.TextBoxFor`  in place of `@Html.EditorFor`?  and Use `@Html.BeginForm()` in the place of `form `

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code Working perfect i seen your Code you may have these Error,

1. you should use `@using (Html.BeginForm())` instead of `<form>`
2. `@Html.ValidationSummary(false)` in place of `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)`
   please see my Code.

   ```
              <div class="container">
               @using (Html.BeginForm())
               {
                   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                   <div class="form-horizontal">
                       <h4>mymodel</h4>
                       <hr />
                       @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

                       <div class="form-group">
                           @Html.LabelFor(model => model.id, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                           <div class="col-md-10">
                               @Html.EditorFor(model => model.id)
                               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.id)
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
                           @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                           <div class="col-md-10">
                               @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name)
                               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name)
                           </div>
                       </div>

                       <div class="form-group">
                           <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                               <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               }
           </div>
           <div>
               @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
           </div>
           <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
           <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
           <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
   ```