# How to pass values of the current model details to controller action in asp.net mvc when checkbox is checked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a table that displays a number of data. what I am trying to do is to send back to the controller the details of the row that has been checked. those details are for instance userName how can I do this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Url)
        </td>
        <td>           
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsApplied,new { id = "MyChk", onchange = "valueChanged()"})
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumberOfApplications)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function valueChanged() {
        if ($('#Mychk').is(":checked"))      
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might add a javascript change even for the input checkbox and save the value to the server whenever he value changes. This example uses JQuery `$.post()` function to send the data, which works well with ASP.NET MVC.

View (cshtml file):

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ modelItem.UserName }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ modelItem.Url }}
        </td>
        <td>    
            <input id="IsApplied" type="checkbox" value="modelItem.IsApplied" value="@modelItem.IsApplied" />
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ modelItem.NumberOfApplications }}
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

<script>
    $('#IsApplied').change(function() {
        var isApplied = this.checked;


        $.post("ControllerName/YourAction", { IsApplied : isApplied }, 
            function(data){
                //do whatever with the response
            });            

    });
</script>
```

ASP.NET MVC Controller file:

```
public class ControllerNameController: Controller // the name ends with 'Controller'
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult YourAction(SetIsAppliedModel model)
    {
        // logic to save model.IsApplied
    }
}

public class SetIsAppliedModel
{
    public bool IsApplied { get; set; }
}
```

Used help:

[jQuery checkbox change and click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031226/jquery-checkbox-change-and-click-event)

[How to send data in jquery.post to mvc controller which use ViewModel as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803292/how-to-send-data-in-jquery-post-to-mvc-controller-which-use-viewmodel-as-paramet)

Comment: But how can I send the value of the checked box

Comment: so for example if the check box has been checked I need to send back the details of that row

Comment: The checkbox for `IsApplied`, added to the form with `CheckBoxFor` method, is an input field and will be sent in form data to the server.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to disable the checkbox on this screen so it only displays the value, since there is a action link to the actual `Edit` form?

Comment: but how to specify which controller and action name that those data will be sent to

Comment: Now I maybe udderstand, this cshtml view prints a list of items, it does not send data back. You will need to create another view `Edit` for editing the item.

Comment: I would like to send the data once the checkbox is checked without the need for the edit

Comment: modified the answer, now the changed IsApplied value is sent to the server with an AJAX call.